# Put tags under the title

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

### Current situation

- Tags should not into titles.
- In an opened question, tags are shown at the very bottom of the question.

### Problem

- If a question was opened via a websearch site (which does not show tags): One has to scroll down all the way until the end of the question, to see if the question really affects oneself

### Suggestion

- Move the list of tags right below the title. Maybe like this:
  [image]

Comment: Indeed. I flagged it.

Comment: @honk but the answer there is no more applicable. the tags are not shown on the side

Comment: @Federico: Yes, I noticed that as well. However, the question is still a duplicate. The linked question might need an up-to-date answer, though. One new answer has already been posted...